# Server is returning cached file

Tags: flask, caching, browser-cache

I am creating the following anchor tag dynamically, to download the file I receive from flask backend. The url in `a.href` is always constant. But the content of `output.mp4` keeps on changing.

However, the content of file I get on a.click() is not changing. The file I get is the one I created atleast 3-4 hours ago. How do I get the updated file, on each `a.click()` call?

```
  var a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = 'http://localhost:5000/download/output'
  a.setAttribute('download', 'output.mp4')
  a.click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost 100% to do with the cache setup on the backend.

A simple solution would be to append a cache breaking flag on the output, such as

`a.setAttribute('download', 'output.mp4?cachebuster=' + Date.now())`